# How can my module add xml sitemap entries?

Tags: 7, xml-sitemap

I have a module with a page callback handler for the path "products". So if the user navigates to products/apples then the module presents a page about our apples, and if they go to products/oranges then etc. These pages include detail about the various products.

I would like XML Sitemap to be populated from my module. After all, it's my module that knows what products exist, their descriptions etc.

Any hook or anything I can use for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base function you call is `xmlsitemap_link_save()`.

I am unaware of any documentation on how to use this, but nodes get added to the sitemap via `xmlsitemap_node_nodeapi()` which in turn calls `xmlsitemap_node_create_link()`.  The code for that should provide some guidance on how to build `$link`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Looks like I just loop through my paths chucking them at `xmlsitemap_link_save()` with `'type'=>'custom'`. Thank you!