# How to add link (via php) to xmlsitemap

Tags: 7, xml-sitemap

I have a site where some pages are "virtual".

The path is :

internal_node/XYZ

where 
* internal_node/% is defined in a hook_menu()
* XYZ is a number

my "internal_node" callback  call an external service using XYZ like argument, get soma data and display this data to the user. All works without problem. And all is legal.

Now I want to add all "interal_node" links to my google's sitemap.

I have installed xmlsitemap, but this module create a google sitemap for only all internal drupal node and my "internal_node" are not a drupal node.

So, how can I add link to xmlsitemap ?

Thanks.

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

you could put those links in a menu and have that menu included to your xmlsitemap.

Comment: Can I insert only one menu in my xmlsitemap or I need to insert all menus ?

Comment: you can specify which menu you want to insert in xmlsitemap

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can add links to the xmlsitemap.

- You can put them on a menu and add those menu links: https://www.drupal.org/node/507674
- You can have your module add them automatically using xmlsitemap_link_save: [How can my module add xml sitemap entries?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16627/how-can-my-module-add-xml-sitemap-entries)
- You can use the hooks from the module to update the sitemap during generation: http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!xmlsitemap!xmlsitemap.api.php/7