# How do I add new fields to the sitemap.xml file generated by the XML Sitemap module?

Tags: 7

Is there a way to add extra fields to the sitemap.xml file created by the [XML Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap/releases/7.x-2.7) module?

By default, it has these fields: URL, last modification date, change frequency, and priority. I'd like to add language, as I'd like to have one sitemap.xml file and not one file per language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can my module add xml sitemap entries?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16627/how-can-my-module-add-xml-sitemap-entries)

Comment: Have you looked into its API? https://git.drupalcode.org/project/xmlsitemap/-/blob/7.x-2.x/xmlsitemap.api.php?ref_type=heads

Comment: @cilefen - all links in the question you linked go to some site that seems to sell steroids or something like that :(

Comment: @cilefen - thank you, I am reading through the API. Still not sure how to use it though

Comment: It is a very old answer but I think little has changed about the API. Fortunately the link I provided above contains the entire API.

Comment: You can use views + any xml output modulke instead of xmlsitemap

Comment: @Nikit - Thank you. Any links you can share that can explain  your strategy?